# Computing the order, inverse, and parity of a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

How do you compute the order, inverse and parity of $\alpha=(12)(43)(13542)(15)(13)(23)$? Please explain all steps taken to get the answer.

I guess my thought process was to first put it into a permutation, but I didn't know how. So then I thought I should break down the middle cycle (idk if that's the correct terminology) 13542 into 2-cycles like the rest.  That's when I got (12)(43)(31)(51)(54)(52)(32)(42)(41)(43) but that seemed like I was doing way too much. So I guess I'm not really sure where or how to start.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: @vadim123 thanks

Comment: **Hint:** Start by writing the cycle decomposition of your permutation.  For example you can check that $2 \to 3$ and $3 \to 2$ so $(2 \ 3)$ will be one cycle.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather find out the *cycle structure* of $\alpha$ itself:

By convention (in most places) permutations are composed from right to left, just as functions ($\,f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))\,$). Input each given number to $\alpha$, they give

> $\alpha(1)=5$ because $(23)$ doesn't touch $1$, then $1$ moves to $3$ then $3$ moves to $5$ in the middle cycle.
>
> $\alpha(5)=4,\quad \alpha(4)= 1.$ That's the cycle $(154)$.
>
> $\alpha(2)=3$, and $\alpha(3)=2$. Check these.

So, we get $\alpha=(154)(23)$.

It is odd ($\,\alpha=(15)(54)(23)\,$). Its inverse is $(145)(23)$. (Note that disjoint cycles *commute* with each other.)
Its order is neither $3$ nor $2$, but $6$.